# Nextjs Image component wont load my images

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

[Nextjs Image component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) wont load my images, I've tried everything I've come across still nothing.

```
<div>
  {output?.map((item) => (
    <div>
      {console.log(`${apiUrl}${item.localImage}`)}
      <Image
        loader={(item) => {
          return `${apiUrl}${item.localImage}`;
        }}
        alt={item.title}
        src={`${apiUrl}${item.localImage}`}
        layout="fill"
        objectFit="contain"
        // height={98}
        // width={77}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

The console.log shows the correct image location.

```
http://localhost:3030/images/b/Painting-with-Both-Hands--Sophie-Walbeoffe.jpg
http://localhost:3030/images/b/DK-The-History-Book.jpg
http://localhost:3030/images/b/Cradle-to-Cradle--(Patterns-of-Life).jpg
http://localhost:3030/images/b/Upstarts.jpg
```

I have added localhost to `next.config.js` with the port and without. I think its something to do with the [loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader).

So what is missing?

Comment: What's the value of apiUrl?

Comment: It's `http://localhost:3030/`

Comment: Ok, did the answer for correcting the loader work for you?

Comment: No, didn't work

Comment: Sorry then my solution is incorrect.

Comment: What path is showing when the images fail to load in the dev tools network tab?

Comment: I get some errors in red. When I follow the links i get 400: BAD_REQUEST
Code: INVALID_IMAGE_OPTIMIZE_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the code for the loader to:

```
loader={() => {
      return `${apiUrl}${item.localImage}`;
    }}
```

Comment: This throws `TypeError: loader is not a function` . Seems the loader must receive a function.

Comment: @Youzef sorry for the wrong suggestion. How about you change it the one above now, because when you puy "item" in that function it creates a new variable which is different from the first “item" used in map. I hope that this is the solution and it works for you.